# Seeking key event library for C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, events

I'm a new C++ programmer who is moving over from Java and Python. As a fun first project I decided to have a go at a simple Snake game. The application has no GUI: Instead, I print the state of the board to the console once per second.

What I'm looking for is a way to make the snake turn with the arrow keys. I thought this would be simple; however, I'm working on a Mac, and all the libraries I've found that handle Mac input events are Objective-C libraries rather than C++ ones.

Does anyone know of a way to capture key input events in C++ on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

For console applications `ncurses` is the way to go for handling key input.